# swift 3 gamecenter: number of participants are always 4

Tags: ios, swift3, gamekit

I made a TurnBased game that was working perfectly with swift 2.
I could successfully change the code to swift 3.2 and correct all the errors about 400, but there is one issue with the game centre that I can not figure out how to fix it.
When through gamecenter viewcontroler I set the number of the participant to “2Player” and then push “Invite Friends” the number of Player that I get is 4 instead of 2!
the gamecenter send a text message to the next participant in which the number of participant is 4 too.
This of course affect the rest of the program a problem that I didn’t have in Swift 2.
This is part of my code:

```
func joinTurnBasedMatch()
{
    let request = GKMatchRequest()
    request.minPlayers = 2
    request.maxPlayers = 4
    request.defaultNumberOfPlayers = 2

    let tbvc = GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController(matchRequest: request)
    tbvc.turnBasedMatchmakerDelegate = self
    present(tbvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func turnBasedMatchmakerViewController(_ viewController: GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController, didFind match: GKTurnBasedMatch)
{
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "To_ViewC_CG", sender: match)
    print("*** Number OF Players ***")
    print(match.participants!.count)
}
```

Do I need to add anything to my code or change anything in it?

Comment: defaultNumberOfPlayers If this property is not set, then the default number of players is equal to the value stored in the maxPlayers property. The default number of players determines the number of invitees shown in the standard matchmaking user interface. The player can choose to override this to add or remove slots.

Comment: looks like you are setting it so I am not sure why this is happening

Comment: The funny part is that when I use an iPad with iOS 9 the program send the correct information, but not with my iPad 2 air with iOS 10 on it. It has something to do with gamecenter new setup.

Comment: Seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41916413/turn-based-matchmaking-not-working-in-ios-10. Out of curiosity, what happens if you reduce .maxPlayers to 3?

Comment: interestingly when I change request.maxPlayers to 3 it shows 3 player even though I invited only 1 player from among my friends.

Comment: The question linked in my other comment looks like Obj-c, so I don't believe this is a swift3.2 issue, but rather and IOS10 issue. It looks like the defaultNumberOfPlayers is not being honored. See the answer I posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41916413/turn-based-matchmaking-not-working-in-ios-10/42043241#42043241

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved in the latest ios update. 
Now it works perfectly.